# Numerical Analysis - Convergence - Newton Raphson

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, newton-raphson

While solving an exercise leaflet, I got stuck on the following :

The equation $x^3 - 2x - 5 = 0$ has exactly one real solution $x_s$ and it belongs to the interval $(2,3)$. Show thoroughly that, if $x_0 >=1$ then the sequence $(x_k)$ that is given by the method Newton-Raphson, converges at the solution $x_s$.

My mind tells me that we shall show that the sequence $(x_k), k>=1$ is decreasing and that it's down bounded (Sorry about the term "down", but I do not know how to properly say it in English, so I translated it boldly from Greek (κάτω φραγμένη).

First of all I started by finding the sequence, which is :

$x_k = x_{k-1} - \frac{x_{k-1}^3 - 2x_{k-1} - 5}{3x_{k-1}^2 -2}$

By finding that it's decreasing and bounded, we can apply the Monotone Convergence Theorem and prove what we need, but I my mind is stuck and I cannot prove that the sequence is decreasing or bounded at this point. Also, I have a question in my mind about how we'll end up showing that the sequence converges to the solution exactly.

Any help will be appreciated ! I'd love and it would help me tons if someone could provide a thorough explanation. Thanks in advance !

Comment: "bounded (from) below"

Comment: Do you know anything about how convexity (or concavity) of $f$ influences the behaviour of the Newton-Raphson method?

Comment: No, not really. We haven't done anything like that thus far, but if you can, please elaborate!

Comment: Make a sketch. If $f$ is strictly convex and increasing, the tangent always intersects the $x$-axis to the right of the zero. Thus $x_{k+1} > x_s$ for all $k$. And since hence $f(x_{k+1}) > 0$, you get $x_{k+2} = x_{k+1} - \dfrac{f(x_{k+1})}{f'(x_{k+1})} < x_{k+1}$. Thus you know the sequence converges to some $\alpha \geqslant x_s$, and it remains to show that $\alpha > x_s$ can't happen. The arguments are essentially the same (with flipped sense of inequalities in two cases) for strictly convex and decreasing functions, or strictly concave and monotonic functions.

Comment: For functions that are convex (concave), but not strictly, and monotonic, basically the same holds, but if the zero lies in an interval where the function is affine, you reach the zero after finitely many steps (and then stay there forever).